# Laravel 5.6 - Do I need to include JQuery or is it already included in the app.js?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have created a Laravel 5.6 project on my local.

I have `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>` in `<head>`

In one of the views, I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery( "#ddtype" ).change(function() {
            alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
        });

    });

</script>
```

but it gives me `jQuery is not defined` error

If I try Bootstrap 4's collapse function, it works fine. Does that mean jQuery is already included?

I have done `npm install` and `npm run dev`

My `resources/js/app.js` requires `bootstrap.js` which looks like (not full code but top few lines) as below

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

Please advise. I have checked in different browsers to make sure no cache issues etc.

**Update**

My layouts/app.blade.php structure is like this -

```
<html>
<head>
....
<!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
....
</head>
<body>

    <div id="app">

        @include('layouts.nav')

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and `myview.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
     .....
     .....
    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery( "#ddtype" ).change(function() {
                alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
            });

        });

    </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: That means that bootstrap includes jquery, I suppose.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. Not sure what is going wrong here?

Comment: `app.js` is included __after__ you use your js-code?

Comment: Yes. Please take a look at my update above. I have added the structure.

Comment: you need to compile (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#installation) (`npm install`) the resources and include the `app.js` (`<script src="/js/app.js"></script>`) to your view

Comment: @Ben that's already included in the main layout. I have found what's causing this issue. If I remove "defer" from my app.js script tag, jQuery becomes available.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

jQuery is loaded via your `app.js`, which is only loaded once the page is ready because of the `defer` attribute in your script tag.

Your inline script tag where you call `jQuery(document).ready` is loaded as the page renders, therefore executed before the `app.js` has been loaded. Hence the error, since jQuery is not yet loaded at that time.

To fix it, simply remove the `defer` attribute from the script tag.

> The defer attribute is a boolean attribute.
>
> When present, it specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing.

For more information about the defer attribute: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: To me this fixed jQuery but then I get this `app.js:37395 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app`

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe It simply means you have no element in your HTML with the `id="app"` attribute.

Comment: Thanks @Chin Leung what frustrated me was this was a fresh Laravel application so why would the attribute be missing? I'll test some more though.

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe By default Laravel provides the JS to have Vue running easily but you have to specify it in your DOM yourself. Otherwise you can remove the new Vue in your **app.js** if you don't plan on using Vue.

Comment: This has been bugging me for the last couple of days. Not one jquery plugin loaded because of the defer. Once removed it all worked